# looking up from array and creating for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could you please explain me why do I write `contacts[x]` in this `(contacts[x].firstName === name)`. Okay understand I create a loop `for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++){}` However I can not understand the meaning of `contacts[x]`. "x" is not in array. How can I pick it just directly from function like that? Is it like index ? I mean it is the x position in array so I pick from there ?

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

//The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName
//the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
//If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
//If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property".
//If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact".

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}
```

Comment: it's not `contacts["x"]` but `contacts[x]` meaning that it uses whatever value `x` has i.e. `contacts[0]`, `contacts[1]`, etc.

Comment: `x` is an integer value which is increasing after each iteration of the loop. Besides an array in JavaScript contains index numbers starts from 0. So `contacts[x]` here represents an element of the array `contacts`.

Comment: Array documentation can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Its only the index value, when you write just x its mean index if you write 'x' (in quotes) then you access and key in object. In your if you wrote contacts[x].firstName, means you accessing the the key firstName in the object on place x in the array contacts.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed so contacts[x][prop] means here that I pick from contacts[0][firstName]. x is one of these contacts 4 starting from 0 to 3. Thank you.

Comment: `contracts` is an `array` which has 4 object as elements and each object is present at an index from 0 to 3. So when you do `contracts[x]` it should return an object at index `x`. To get a property of object at `x` index you do `contracts[x].[prop]`. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `x` is the index. For example, if `x = 1` then `contacts[x]` is the same as `contacts[1]`. It is looping through each number between `0` and the `length` of `contacts`.

Normally `i` is the variable name in place of `x`, meaning integer. Like this. But any name can be use (like `x`).

```js
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var item = array[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, If you console log the x within the loop scope it'll output the index

```
 for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    console.log(x);
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
```

So basically the loop initializes x to 0 and iterates through your loop code and increments x, In the meantime, you access the index of the array using variable "x" ( `contacts[x]`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.find()`:

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

const lookUp = (name, prop) => {
  const profile = contacts.find(c => c.firstName === name);
  if (profile) {
    if (profile.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return profile[prop];
    }
    return 'No such Property';
  }
  return 'No such contact';
}

console.log(lookUp('Sherlock', 'lastName'));
console.log(lookUp('Sherloc', 'lastName'));
console.log(lookUp('Sherlock', 'lastNameasdds'));
```